# The method findViewById(int) is undefined for the type and the controller of the adapter too

Tags: java, android, listview, adapter

I get this error: The method findViewById(int) is undefined for the type.

I got a fragment:

```
public class EventFragment extends Fragment  {


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, 
            ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.event, 
                container, false);

     // Check for an open session
        Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
        if (session != null && session.isOpened()) {
            // Get the user's data
            makeFQLRequest();

        }
        return view;
    }
```

This is my method makeFQLRequest();

```
private static String url="https://www.dropbox.com/s/rhk01nqlyj5gixl/jsonparsing.txt?dl=1";


        //Create a JSON parser Instance ----- Used JSON parser from Android
        JSONParser jParser=new JSONParser();

        //Getting JSON string from URL ------ Used JSON Array from Android
        JSONArray json=jParser.getJSONFromUrl(url);

        List<WhateverObject> yourData = new ArrayList<WhateverObject>();

        try {
            for(int i=0;i<json.length();i++)
            {
                JSONObject c=json.getJSONObject(i);// Used JSON Object from Android

                //Storing each Json in a string variable
                int AGE=c.getInt("age");
                String NAME=c.getString("name");
                String CITY=c.getString("city");
                String GENDER=c.getString("Gender");
                String BIRTHDATE=c.getString("birthdate");


                yourData.add(new WhateverObject(NAME, CITY, GENDER, BIRTHDATE));

            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
if(yourData != null){

        ListView yourListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.itemListView);

        ListAdapter customAdapter = new ListAdapter(this, R.layout.itemlistrow, yourData);

        yourListView.setAdapter(customAdapter);

    }
```

Now I cant even test my code because it says The method findViewById(int) is undefined for the type and also that the constructor of the adapter is undefined. Can anybody help me what to do I'm stuck for more then 2 hours now ...

Comment: Try passing a `context` object and use it (so if you pass `con` use `con.findViewById(...);`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use getActivity() in your fragment to retrieve a view like this:

```
ListView yourListView = (ListView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.itemListView);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use getView(). This will return the root view for the fragment, with this you can call findViewById().

```
YourView ref= (YourView ) getView().findViewById(R.id.foo);
```

Comment: Yes this works but can you help me with the adapter thing? The constructor LustAdapter blablabla undefined

Comment: Can You Please Share your ListAdapter Constructor?